# My dog is chewing everything yellow

Tags: dogs, chewing

My dog does not chew much.
But recently, it seems like she wants to utterly destroy everything yellow.
She ripped apart pencils, yellow alligator wires, etc.
Why does she chew those, and why does she prefer yellow?

Comment: What colour is she?  Any yellow / golden colouring in her pedigree?

Comment: @Judith I don't think so, she's a black terrier mix with a white beard...

Comment: "And it was all yellow..." (Song lyric, sorry.)